# How to filter order numbers by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with many rows that looks something like this:

```
Order_id Part_id    Description   GL_code
12345    Gk123      Gun mount     6850
12345    null       Freight       4050.2
12346    Blac       Lock          6790
12346    null       Freight       4050
```

I want to make a query that returns all order information where the `part_id` is a `GK% number` or a `Blac number` and the order has a freight `GL_code` of `4050.2`.

The `Freight` is in the description column and in a different row than the `part_id`.

I do not want to include all the `Blac` and `GK% parts` that do not have `freight` and `4050.2` on the order.

I've only been able to get all 4050.2's or all GK%'s and Blac's.

Comment: Can you post the sql query you have so far

Comment: Please provide us with the desired results; what records do you want the query to return?  Also, what have you tried?  Giving the community your starting-point query often helps ensure everyone is on the same page, along with showing your own effort on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a correlated subquery that makes sure that there exists a row for the same order with the Freight code 4050.2:

```
select * from tab t
where (Part_id = 'Blac' or Part_id like 'GK%') 
and exists (
    select 1 
    from tab 
    where Order_id = t.Order_id 
      and Description = 'Freight' 
      and GL_code = '4050.2' -- remove the quotes if this is a number and not a char value
    )
```

With your sample data this would return:

```
Order_id    Part_id Description GL_code
12345       Gk123   Gun mount   6850
```

Another option would be to use a purely set based query:

```
select Order_id from tab where (Part_id = 'Blac' or Part_id like 'GK%')
intersect 
select Order_id from tab where Description = 'Freight' and GL_code = '4050.2'
```

Or if you just want to rows with Freight you can just invert the conditions:

```
select * from shipper_line t
where Description = 'Freight' and GL_code = '4050.2' 
and exists (
    select 1 
    from shipper_line 
    where Order_id = t.Order_id 
      and (Part_id = 'Blac' or Part_id like 'GK%') 
);
```

Comment: This worked. It gave me just the rows that had freight on them.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to join the table to itself; SQL is better at cross-column checks than cross-row checks.

```
Select a.* from MyTable a
inner join MyTable b
on a.Order_ID = b.Order_ID and b.Part_ID is null and b.Description = 'Freight' and b.GL_code = 4050.2
where (a.Part_ID like 'GK%' or a.Part_ID like 'Blac%')
```

You can also use `exists` or a subquery:

```
select * from MyTable a
where (a.Part_ID like 'GK%' or a.Part_ID like 'Blac%')
and exists 
  (select 1 from MyTable b 
  where a.order_ID = b.order_ID and b.Description = 'Freight' and b.GL_code = 4050.2)

select * from MyTable a
where (a.Part_ID like 'GK%' or a.Part_ID like 'Blac%')
and order_ID in 
  (select order_ID from MyTable 
  where Description = 'Freight' and GL_code = 4050.2)
```

Edit: Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a778c/1/0

Comment: select * from shipper_line as sl join cust_order_line  as col on sl.cust_order_id = col.cust_order_id and cust_order_line_no = col.line_no
where (col.Part_ID like 'GK%' or col.Part_ID like '%Blac%')
and sl.cust_order_ID in 
  (select sl.cust_order_ID from shipper_line as sl join cust_order_line  as col on sl.cust_order_id = col.cust_order_id and cust_order_line_no = col.line_no 
  where sl.misc_reference = 'Freight' and sl.GL_revenue_acct_id = '4065.2')
  order by sl.cust_order_id

Comment: This query gets me the part numbers and orders I need, but I really want to just see the gl_revenue amounts. In other words, I want all the freight rows that meets all of these conditions.

Comment: @ian, I would recommend modifying the first option, in that case, to `select b.*` instead of `a.*`.   That will return the freight rows, rather than the part_id rows.  If you have more questions beyond what you posted originally, it may be wise to start a new question rather than adding more scope to this one.

Answer (score 0):

please try this query. As per the your question, this seems to also fulfill the important condition:

> The Freight is in the description column and in a different row than
>   the part_id.

```
select l.order_id from 
(
select order_id,rownum from 
   (
     select *, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by Part_id, Description, GL_code ) as rownum from tblt
   ) t 
where (part_id like 'GK%' or part_id like 'Blac%')  and order_id in (select order_id from tblt where GL_code like '4050.2')
) l
inner join 
 (select * from 
   (
     select *, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by Part_id, Description, GL_code ) as rownum 
     from tblt
   ) t2 
where t2.description like 'Freight') r
on l.order_id=r.order_id and l.rownum<>r.rownum
```

fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/620c05/8

Comment: While the query does seem to give the right result, it seems awfully complicated with 6 different select statements and window functions.